# jquery dropdown list works, but it doesn't with more lists

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, dropdown

I I'm working on five independent lists, I'm using a jquery but only one list works. I ask for advice because I cannot understand if there are some conflicts or the jquery code is wrong. But I don't see id on script, only class.
I'm using flexbox, and I added the script on page (wordpress theme:customizr). In funtions.php there's Smart jquery inclusion.
thank you

```
<div class="cont">
<div class="elemento item33">
<section class="sectionlist">
<div class="contlist">
<div class="control">
   <span class="dropdown-trigger"><strong>Max</strong></span> </p>
<ul class="box dropdown-items">
<li class="dropdown-item">a</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">b</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">c</li>
</ul></div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<div class="elemento item33">
<section class="sectionlist">
<div class="contlist">
<div class="control">
 <span class="dropdown-trigger">Robert</span> </p>
<ul class="box dropdown-items">
<li class="dropdown-item">1</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">d</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">e</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">f</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">g</li>
</ul></div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<div class="elemento item33">
<section class="sectionlist">
<div class="contlist">
<div class="control">
 <span class="dropdown-trigger">Sam</span> </p>
<ul class="box dropdown-items">
<li class="dropdown-item">1</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">h</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">i</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">j</li>
<li class="dropdown-item">k</li>
</ul></div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</div> <!--and 2 more list--->

<script>
var trigger = document.querySelector(".dropdown-trigger");
trigger.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.querySelector(".dropdown-items").classList.toggle("is-open");
});
</script>

.sectionlist {text-align: center; width: 320px;}
.dropdown-trigger {color:#004a8f;padding:0;}
.dropdown-trigger:hover {cursor:pointer;}
.dropdown-trigger::after {content: "\25BD"; color:#ccc; 
padding-left:1em;}
.control {border: 1px solid #eee;}
.dropdown-items { display:none;
border-radius:1px;left:0;position:relative;top:0;z-index:1000;
text-align:left;line-height:1.5em;padding:0!important;  }
.dropdown-item {padding:.5em 2em;white-space:inherit;}
.dropdown-divider {border: 1px solid #eee;}
.dropdown-item:hover {background-color:#eee;}
.dropdown-items.is-open {display: block;width: inherit;}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach to your problem

btw - You say you're using jquery, then dont write to many code and for better reading, you should proper format your code, its making more readable for others.

Here is the example of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/0rven7zt/3/

```
<style>
.sectionlist {text-align: center; width: 320px;}
.dropdown-trigger {color:#004a8f;padding:0;}
.dropdown-trigger:hover {cursor:pointer;}
.dropdown-trigger::after {content: "\25BD"; color:#ccc; 
padding-left:1em;}
.control {border: 1px solid #eee;}
.dropdown-items { display:none;
border-radius:1px;left:0;position:relative;top:0;z-index:1000;
text-align:left;line-height:1.5em;padding:0!important;  }
.dropdown-item {padding:.5em 2em;white-space:inherit;}
.dropdown-divider {border: 1px solid #eee;}
.dropdown-item:hover {background-color:#eee;}
.dropdown-items.is-open {display: block;width: inherit;}
</style>

<div class="cont">
    <div class="elemento item33">
        <section class="sectionlist">
            <div class="contlist">
                <div class="control">
                    <span class="dropdown-trigger"><strong>Max</strong></span>
                    <ul class="box dropdown-items">
                        <li class="dropdown-item">a</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">b</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">c</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="elemento item33">
        <section class="sectionlist">
            <div class="contlist">
                <div class="control">
                    <span class="dropdown-trigger">Robert</span>
                    <ul class="box dropdown-items">
                        <li class="dropdown-item">1</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">d</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">e</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">f</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">g</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="elemento item33">
        <section class="sectionlist">
            <div class="contlist">
                <div class="control">
                    <span class="dropdown-trigger">Sam</span>
                    <ul class="box dropdown-items">
                        <li class="dropdown-item">1</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">h</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">i</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">j</li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">k</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown-trigger').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Im sorry. So your solution doesn't work in my customizr theme (buttons will close when clicked, doesn't open), probably javascript has some problem. Anyway many thanks for the solution. +1